# AWS - The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records error

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'am trying to upload a picture to aws s3 using aws-sdk to configure aws and multer-s3 to upload to aws.

I am getting a  "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records."....even though my key is showing as active on aws console....and is valid....where did I go wrong?

```
> let aws = require('aws-sdk'); aws.config.update({
>     secretAccessKey:"my-access-key",
>     accessKeyId:"my-access-Id",
>     region: 'ap-south-1'  }); const s3 = new aws.S3(); var uploadDP = multer({
>     storage: multerS3({
>         s3: s3,
```

and so on....

I assure you my secretAccessKey and accessKeyId are legit
and ahowing active in IAM on aws..
*showing
Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: did you check region ? ap-south is right one ?

Comment: @harshmanvar 'ap-south-1'....is the right zone (mumbai)...i chose the same in aws account.

Comment: Does the key start with `AKIA` or `ASIA`?

Answer (score 1):

Rename the properties of your configuration object as below:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

const awsConfig = {
  aws_access_key_id: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  aws_secret_access_key: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  Bucket: process.env.S3_IMAGES_BUCKET_NAME,
};

aws.config.update(awsConfig);
```

These names are based on information from AWS documentation.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-shared.html

and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-configuring-buckets.html